# Assign function result to a table variable

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-queries

The SQL Server (2000/2005) function gets the table name and the field name as parameters and returns results from a dynamic query within the function. The results should be assigned to a `Table` variable which will be used further in a stored procedure.  How to achieve this?

I am getting error: "Only functions and extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function."

```
Declare @Data as table (FieldValue varchar(100))
insert into @Data select * from MyFunction ('Person.Address','AddressID')     

-- Function
Alter function MyFunction (
   @TableName varchar(100), @FieldName varchar(100) 
) returns @GetData table (
   FieldValue  varchar(100) 
) as
begin
        Declare @SQL varchar(250)
        Set @SQL = 'Select '+@FieldName+ ' from '+ @TableName
        Exec sp_executesql @SQL     
        return
end
```

Comment: -1.  Don't use dynamic Sql this way.  Refer to sommarskog:  http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: +1. @David: He is asking, no need to downvote because he is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how this works with functions, but if you have a Stored Procedure that returns a resultset, you can insert that into a table variable using INSERT EXEC statements.

```
INSERT @TableVariable
EXEC spYourProcedure
```

As long as the fields match that will work. Otherwise you can use:

```
INSERT @TableVariable (FieldInSp1, FieldInSp2)
EXEC spYourProcedure
```

This way you can pass data between stored procedures. See this page on [INSERT EXEC Statements](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#INSERTEXEC) for some extra information.

Answer (score 8):

just to close the loop...

here is the syntax for calling the function and putting those results in a table variable

small build on @simons solution

this ran on sql2012 and sql2014.

[ dont forget to close off the table statement. Easy enough to do if you have the table all on a single line. ]

```
declare @t table(field1  nvarchar(100) )

insert @t select * from dbo.Cool_1Field_Function( 'parm1' ,'parm2')
select * from @t
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It's the only one that uses a function and not a procedure.

Comment: too bad you cannot do: `declare @t table(field1  nvarchar(100) ) = dbo.Cool_1Field_Function( 'parm1' ,'parm2')`

Comment: @costa, add it to the list of 'stuff that would be cool if....'.   I have  a reasonable  list for sql   :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use "exec" in a user defined function. UDFs must be side effect free.