# Swap two records excluding few columns using stored procedure in SQL Server 2000/2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to create a stored procedure (for SQL Server 2000 / 2005) to swap 2 records excluding a few columns, it has to get "table name", "record id (2 id)" and "column to exclude" as a parameter. Here columns are dynamic as we get 'table' as a parameter and number of columns may be more than 50.

Here I believe, "update [table name] set [field] = [value] ......"

Type statements will be very lengthy as the number of columns will be more than 50 and it is a variant.

Is there any simple way to swap records in SQL Server 2000/2005?

Comment: Do you really need to use dynamic SQL? I have looked at your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464191/assign-function-result-to-a-table-variable and it it also trying to use dynamic SQL. Is there any special reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this answer by Tom H.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484040/swapping-the-2-rows-in-ms-sql-server-retaining-the-original-primary-key-and-witho#484787) to similar question.

Also [this solution posted on SQLServerCentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic560225-169-1.aspx) may be helpful to you (the site requires registration but it is free)